# Why is my Genereted Rig on the ground?

Tags: rigging

I am trying to generate a rig for a figure I created. I am using blender 2.83.4.

When I generate it, it is below the figure. Like it is oriented on the z=0 plane. I gave both the armature and the figure the same origin. Why did it sink through the floor?

[image: Rig below figure]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because of difference in location of armature origin , in Object and Edit Modes.

Simply reapplying armature location , will sync it in both modes.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, @Starzar, that worked